# How to re-initialized flutter animation in previous page when click android back button?

Tags: android, flutter, animation

flutter
page A has an animation , most code is in "initState" .
page A has navigated to page B.
when click back button on anroid machine to page A again , i want page A to replay the animation on page A . but i don't want to add some "animationcontroller.reset()" and "animationcontroller.forward()" in "build" method in page A .
how should i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Navigator's push methods are a Futures, you could "await" them to resolve and then execute the code to reset the animation.
Like:

```
Navigator.push(...).then((_) => _animationController.reset());
```